# SWIFT, fatal error (index out of range) при переборе элементов массива

Tags: массивы, swift, циклы, for

подскажите, почему появляется fatal error при попытке удалить из массива числа у которых остаток от деления = 0? [image: скриншот]

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите код не картинкой, а текстом. Так с ним будет проще работать

Comment: Подозреваю, что ошибка в том, что Вы удаляете элементы из массива, по которым на каждой итерации хотите пройти...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы хотите именно так удалить элементы из массива, то разверните итератор:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for (index, element) in a.enumerated().reversed() {
    if (element.isMultiple(of: 2)) {
        a.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

А лучше использовать специальный метод коллекции, лаконичнее и быстрее:

```
a.removeAll(where: { $0.isMultiple(of: 2) })
```

---

Что происходит при итерации в прямом порядке:

```
Имеется массив [1, 2, 3, 4]
Проход по по массиву и удаление:
индекс: 0, элемент: 1, ничего не удалено
[1, 2, 3, 4]
индекс: 1, элемент: 2, удаление по индексу и сдвиг оставшейся части:
[1, 3, 4]
индекс: 2, элемент: 3, ничего не удалено:
[1, 3, 4]
индекс: 3, элемент: 4, попытка удаления, краш.
```

Что происходит после разворота:

```
Имеется массив [1, 2, 3, 4]
Проход по по массиву и удаление в обратном порядке и удаление с конца:
индекс: 3, элемент: 4, удаление:
[1, 2, 3]
индекс: 2, элемент: 3, ничего не удалено:
[1, 2, 3]
индекс: 1, элемент: 2, удаление:
[1, 3]
индекс: 0, элемент: 1, ничего не удалено:
[1, 3]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите, а для чего нужно разворачивать итератор?

Comment: @ГеннадийНовиков, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка появляется из-за того, что вы удаляете элементы из массива, а цикл, как "создал" себе количество индексов для итераций по стартовому размеру массива, так по нему и пытается пробежаться, вы количество индексов уменьшаете и в итоге он обращается к несуществующему номеру элемента массива.

Кроме того, в этом коде есть еще одна ошибка. Номера элементов массива, созданные для прохода цикла, которые поочередно присваиваются переменной index, остаются неизменными даже после удаления элементов из массива, а вот метод remove(at:) удаляет элементы из массива в соотвествии с их реальными индексами, на момент удаления. И если добавить в ваш код принты:

```
import Foundation

var array1 = [1, 20, 35, 4, 5, 7, 10]

for (index, value) in array1.enumerated() {
  print("Array: ", array1, " index:", index, " Value:", value, " array [\(index)] =", array1[index])
  if value % 2 == 0 {
    print("value in if = ", value)
    array1.remove(at: index)
  }
  print("Array: ", array1, " index:", index, " Value:", value, " array [\(index)] =", array1[index], "\n")
}
```

то по выводу в консоли:

```
Array:  [1, 20, 35, 4, 5, 7, 10]  index: 0  Value: 1  array [0] = 1
Array:  [1, 20, 35, 4, 5, 7, 10]  index: 0  Value: 1  array [0] = 1 

Array:  [1, 20, 35, 4, 5, 7, 10]  index: 1  Value: 20  array [1] = 20
value in if =  20
Array:  [1, 35, 4, 5, 7, 10]  index: 1  Value: 20  array [1] = 35 

Array:  [1, 35, 4, 5, 7, 10]  index: 2  Value: 35  array [2] = 4
Array:  [1, 35, 4, 5, 7, 10]  index: 2  Value: 35  array [2] = 4 

Array:  [1, 35, 4, 5, 7, 10]  index: 3  Value: 4  array [3] = 5
value in if =  4
Array:  [1, 35, 4, 7, 10]  index: 3  Value: 4  array [3] = 7 

Array:  [1, 35, 4, 7, 10]  index: 4  Value: 5  array [4] = 10
Array:  [1, 35, 4, 7, 10]  index: 4  Value: 5  array [4] = 10 

Fatal error: Index out of range:
```

становится видно, что во втором случае срабатывания вашего условия оператор if "ловит" число 4 (которое соответствует условию), а в итоге из массива удаляется число 5 (не соответствующее условию), потому что, до этого, было удалено число 20 и все реальные индексы "съехали"на 1, в отличие от тех, которые себе "сохранил" для итерации for.

Comment: Большое спасибо, за развернутый ответ!